# How to create a hole in the street?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a hole in the street using blender. I've tracked my footage and set up a scene. I could cut a hole in a plane and put a cylinder under that, but then the plane would be visible, and it would obscure part of the street. My question is: how do I make it so that the hole looks like it's in the street (without showing anything below the street) without having a plane obscure part of the street?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVPcT0dJmoY

Comment: @FarewellStackExchange You [think wrong](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link), links to answers are not answers and are discouraged here

Comment: @FarewellStackExchange https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382/what-is-wrong-about-answering-with-a-link